# Pointing to variable that only exists within function C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am currently trying to learn C by reading "The C Programming Language". I am trying to figure things such as pointers but I encountered an example that I can't get my mind around.
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLVjw.png).
An array of pointers is being passed as a parameter to the given function and, it points to variables that were created within the function, to my understanding.

```
lineptr[nlines++] = p;
```

Is this only viable because of the alloc function used before?
How does this work, is this a safe way to code this or should it be avoided?

Comment: Please try to create a [mcve] to show us *in* the question itself. Questions should really be self-contained without need for external links (least of all to images of text). Also please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, coming in `lineptr` is an array of pointers. Hopefully they are all NULL, because otherwise we will have a memory leak, but still we have our array.

```
p0 | p1 | p2 | p3 |...
```

`alloc` allocates some chunk of memory of size `len` that (being very loose with terminology here) "lives" somewhere outside the function. It returns a pointer to that memory. We are then free to put this pointer in the array.

When the function returns, the caller will then be able to access the memory allocated by `alloc` that "lives" outside the function through the pointer stored in the array.

If you can explain in more detail why you are worried about this code, perhaps there is a better answer for you.